# Integration by Parts with a logarithm

Tags: calculus, integration

Im not sure how i go about integrating a function being:
$$\int^{\sqrt{2}}_{1} r^{3}\log({r^2}) dr$$

I assume you use parts but it keeps making me go round in circles.
Any help would be appreciated.

My attempt was:
$$u=log(r^{2}) \rightarrow u'=\frac{2}{r},$$ $$v=\frac{r^4}{4} \rightarrow v'=r^{3}$$

so using the equation $uv- \int uv'$ i get:
$$\frac{r^{4}}{4}log(r^{2})- \int log(r^{2})r^{3}$$

Comment: Show your effort.

Comment: Hint: first substitute $u=r^2$

Comment: If you don't want to make the substitution for any reason, note that $\log (r^n)=n \log (r)$. That makes it pretty simple from there.

Comment: Your equation is mixed up: you're trying to integrate $uv'$ by integrating $uv'$ (i.e. exactly the same expression).  One of those $uv'$ terms should be $u'v$!  That's why it looked like you were going in circles...

Answer (score 2):

Make this substitution before you use Integration by parts:
$$u = r^2$$

Answer (score 2):

Recall that $\log(r^2) = 2\log r$.  So then
\begin{align}
  \int_1^{\sqrt{2}} r^3 \log(r^2) \, dr
    &= \int_1^{\sqrt{2}} r^3 \cdot 2 \log r \, dr\\[0.3cm]
    &= 2\int_1^{\sqrt{2}} r^3 \log r \, dr
\end{align}
Now let $u = \log r$ so that $dv = r^3 \, dr$, and $du = \dfrac{1}{r} \, dr$ (I'm assuming by $\log$ you mean natural log and not common log) and $v = \dfrac{1}{4}r^4$.  So then
\begin{align}
  2\int_1^{\sqrt{2}} r^3 \log r \, dr
    &= 2\left[\frac{1}{4}r^4\log r\bigg|_1^{\sqrt{2}} - \int_1^{\sqrt{2}} \frac{1}{4}r^4 \cdot \frac{1}{r} \, dr\right]
\end{align}

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

You are not working by parts the right way.

$$\int u'vdr=uv-\int uv'dr$$ yields

$$\int r^3\ln(r^2)dr=\frac{r^4}4\ln(r^2)-\int\frac{r^4}4\frac{2dr}r=\frac{r^4}4\ln(r^2)-\frac{r^4}8.$$

Answer (score 0):

Logarithms are good to differentiate, powers are good to integrate.  So call this $\int u \; dv$ with $u = \log(r^3)$ and $dv = r^3\; dr$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_{1}^{\sqrt{2}}r^3\ln(r^2)\space\text{d}r=$$

---

Integrate by parts, $\int f\space\text{d}g=fg-\int g\space\text{d}f$ where:

$$f=\ln(r),\text{d}g=r^3\space\text{d}r,\text{d}f=\frac{1}{r}\space\text{d}r,g=\frac{r^4}{4}$$

---

$$\left[\frac{r^4\ln(r)}{2}\right]_{1}^{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{1}{2}\int_{1}^{\sqrt{2}}r^3\space\text{d}r=$$

---

Use $\int y^b\space\text{d}y=\frac{y^{b+1}}{b+1}+\text{C}$:

---

$$\left[\frac{r^4\ln(r)}{2}\right]_{1}^{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{r^4}{4}\right]_{1}^{\sqrt{2}}=$$
$$\frac{1}{2}\left[r^4\ln(r)\right]_{1}^{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{1}{8}\left[r^4\right]_{1}^{\sqrt{2}}=$$
$$\frac{1}{2}\left(\left(\sqrt{2}\right)^4\ln(\sqrt{2})-1^4\ln(1)\right)-\frac{1}{8}\left(\left(\sqrt{2}\right)^4-1^4\right)=$$
$$\frac{1}{2}\left(4\cdot\ln(\sqrt{2})-0\right)-\frac{1}{8}\left(4-1\right)=$$
$$2\ln(\sqrt{2})-\frac{3}{8}=$$
$$\ln(2)-\frac{3}{8}$$